# Regular Expressions in Erlang. Adding additional match in a result list

Tags: regex, erlang

I am learning how fetching strings in Erlang works with Regular Expressions.
Please explain to me why when I execute regular expression for a list of elements whose values are a sequence from 0 to 255, values greater than 127 fall into the resulting list?

```
Expected = true,
ValidCharacterList = lists:seq(0, 255),

RegularExpression = "[[:ascii:]]",
{ok, MP} = re:compile(RegularExpression),
{match, _} = re:run(ValidCharacterList, MP),
Result = true,
?assertEqual(Expected, Result).
```

The result is all elements of that sequence (from 0 to 255).

[Full code example](https://github.com/rustkas/Introducing-Regular-Expressions-by-Erlang/blob/main/code/ch02/ex01_rime_intro/lib/posix_notation/test/posix_12_ascii_tests.erl).

[More code example](https://github.com/rustkas/Introducing-Regular-Expressions-by-Erlang/tree/main/code/ch02/ex01_rime_intro/lib/posix_notation/test)s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX's `:ascii:` is defined as `[\x00-\x7F]`. Note, however that Erlang [states](https://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html)

> There is another character class, ascii, that erroneously matches Latin-1 characters instead of the 0-127 range specified by POSIX. This cannot be fixed without altering the behaviour of other classes, so we recommend matching the range with [\0-\x7f] instead.